# What does the number next to the review button signify?

Tags: support, notifications

My question really says it all, there is an orange number next to the review button - what does it signify - it isn't the number of posts needing reviewing is it - that seems to be different?

Just took a screenshot, newly refreshed page:

[image]

It shows 1 in the review button (orange box) but 7 in total, and 3 different sections that need reviewing.

Answer (score 3):

It is the number of available Suggested Edits to review. But keep in mind that it doesn't refresh automatically.
It reloads when you refresh or you go another page.

So if there was a `1` next to the review button and you had the page open for a while, once you click the `1`, there is a chance that there won't be anything to review.

Comment: For >10kers it's the total amount of reviews in the whole site.

Comment: But OP is still in the 2k range